# AngularJS: uncaught object because of services and modules dependencies

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-module

I have a 'maps-services' module with a 'MapService' service as below:

```
angular.module('maps-services', [])
.service('MapService', [$log, function($log) {
    this.initMap = function() {
    }
    this.updateMap = function() {   
    }
}]);

I also have a 'maps' module depending on 'maps-services' as below:
angular.module('maps', [
   'maps-services'
]);
```

When I had a dependency on 'maps' in another module, I get an uncaught object error with the message:

"[$injector:nomod] Module 'ngLocale' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.11/$injector/nomod?p0=ngLocale"

I don't understand what's going on and how I could debug the module loading to understand better where the problem is.

Could you please help me ?

Regards.

Comment: try to change $log into a string `.service('MapService', ['$log', function($log) {`

Comment: Strange. Do you use an `ng-locale` directive anywhere in your views?

Comment: I don't use ngLocale anywhere in my code.

Comment: Any chance you found a solution to this?

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem. Only happens on my production servers (digital ocean & heroku), but not an issue locally. Driving me positively insane.

Answer (score 1):

## 80s compilers' style

This exception message reminds me of error messages 80s compilers used to throw.

Basically when Angular throws:

> Module 'ngLocale' is not available!

It means to say:

> One of your modules wasn't loaded (but not ngLocale).

See [this](http://www.johnpapa.net/easy-fix-to-a-common-angular-module-error/) and [this](http://jamesreubenknowles.com/angularjs-nglocale-error-1952/comment-page-1) for more info.

Now why wasn't *your* module loaded, or what module is it, is for you to work out. In my case, having this

```
angular.module( 'treeDemoApp' )
```

instead of this

```
angular.module( 'treeDemoApp', [] )
```

was enough for Angular to throw this message. But you code clearly has the `[]`.

## Chrome Bug?

There are some suggestions ([1](http://devnote.stokemaster.com/2014/07/super-beginner-guide-to-angularjs.html), [2](http://www.congral.com/2014/05/29/have-you-already-encountered-the-uncaught-object-exception/)) that this is due to a bug in chrome.